# Positioning UILabel inside a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

Trying to position a `UILabel` above some text, but the elements are "stepping" on each other. I positioned them with x,y,h,w such that they should not do this but alas, they are. You can see in the screenshot that the label text "Abalone"  and the text are commingled. What changes do I need to make here? I've already tried changing the x,y,w,h values to no great effect...

[image]

```
txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,280,300)];
[txtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14]];
txtView.text = word.definition;
txtView.editable = NO;
txtView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[txtView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([txtView.text length], 0)];
txtView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
txtView.maximumZoomScale = 10;

UILabel *wordTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 20)];
wordTitle.text = word.term;
[txtView addSubview:wordTitle];


[detailsViewController.view addSubview:txtView];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you are adding the label view as a subview to `UITextview`. You have to reserve some space for the label view in the `UITextview`. You can either add some padding to the textView, which can be confusing, because padding in `UITextView` is not constant and varies based on the font size. Or you can add your `UILabel` directly to the `detailsViewController.view` and start your `UITextView` below the label.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Right you are. This worked.  [detailsViewController.view addSubview:wordTitle];
    [detailsViewController.view addSubview:txtView]; Thanks!

Comment: You may also consider this approach: Create a custom UIView class, and position the UILabel and UITextView, and then add the UIView as a subView to detailViewController. Then you have the option to just set the label.text and textview.text within your custom class of UIView. Glad that it worked.